# Unicode in C using Eclipse IDE and Linux Redhat, relation between ttf, utf and charset

Tags: linux, unicode

> I am new to c , but i tried to compile unicode in c and worked with a sample program to 
>   print kannada text, it is working fine . But in my project i need to use fribidi 0.19.6.
>
> I do not have idea on character set and utf and ttf font. If I want to use kannada font in > linux what should i do . which ttf download package should i download for kannada fonts?
>   I have idea on character set and my doubt all about ttf and utf only
>
> Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating unicode text, with modern opentype smart fonts, especially in the CJK domain like kannada, is a very complex problem. It involves many libraries, including fribidi (but not only).

http://behdad.org/text/

I strongly suggest using a high-level library like pango or harfbuzz-ng and not trying to reimplement support from the bottom up. Pango will manage fribidi and other parts of the fonts stack for you. Many very bright people have struggled for years to write those, and they're not perfect yet. There is no way you will do better alone in any reasonable amount of time especially when you don't even understand basic concepts.